# Подсчет строк в textbox'e

Tags: .net, c++

Нужно записать в переменную число строк в вставленном тексте. Как это реализовать?

заранее спс

**с++ cli**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, я уже нашел ответ на свой вопрос

```
textBox1->Lines->Length
```

Answer (score 2):

Посчитайте кол-во "\n" и достаточно.